# How can I set up advanced TCP/IP settings on OS X?

Tags: macos, networking

I need to apply some advanced TCP/IP settings on my Windows PC in order to access the local network at my office.

Here is how it looks on Windows:

[image]

How can I do the same on OS X (El Capitan)?

I could'n find such settings... I managed to set static IP (first window), but what's on the second one I cannot recreate...

When I ping a host I should be able to access I get this

```
ping **.**.**
PING **.**.** (192.168.3.7): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
```

On Windows I had to use the following command some time ago, when I had a similar problem

```
route add 192.168.3.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.30 -p
route add 192.168.151.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.30 -p
```

But the OS X alternative didn't work.

I was told to try

```
sudo route -n add -net 192.168.151.0/24 192.168.10.30
```

But didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings you show from Windows can be set in OSX using `networksetup`. This includes items you set in Control Panel/Internet Settings like proxy, proxybypass and more. Check the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) for more info or just run `man networksetup`.

More specific to your question, the settings on the "IP Settings" tab can be set with

```
sudo networksetup -setadditionalroutes <networkservice> [ <dest> <mask> <gateway> ]*
```

Here's what the man page says about this option:

> **-setadditionalroutes** *networkservice [dest1 mask1 gate1] [dest2 mask2 gate2] ... [destN maskN gateN]*
>
> Use this command to set the list of IPv4 additional routes configured for the service. Each route is specified as a (destination address, subnet mask, gateway address) tuple. Specifying no tuples clears the list of routes.

Note that you may still need to set the route tables as you've indicated. I'm not sure as I've never run a setup like yours. GL